# How can I find all the historical offset transition dates for a timezone?

Tags: ios, swift, timezone

I'm trying to write an app that displays information about a given timezone. It displays which periods of time that timezone is observing DST, and which periods of time it is not. Most importantly, it highlights times where the timezone changes *irregularly*, such as when Britain observed *double* DST during WWII, or when Samoa skipped a day in 2011.

For that, I would need to get a list of all the historical timezone offset transitions, as stored in the TZ database (I think there is a copy of the database in every macOS/iOS device). To be more specific, a "transition" (similar to [`java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html)) is modelled by the following 3 things:

- the `Date` when it happened
- the GMT offset in seconds before it happened
- the GMT offset in seconds after it happened

From what I can see from the [`TimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone) API docs, there is no built-in method that does this (unlike how `java.time` [does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getTransitions--)). The closest method I could find is [`nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293768-nextdaylightsavingtimetransition), but that only tells me the transition date of one transition, when given a date, and I'm also not sure what date to give.

How can I get the list of transitions?

Example output for `Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh`:

```
Transition at 1906-06-30T16:53:20Z from 25600 to 25590
Transition at 1911-04-30T16:53:30Z from 25590 to 25200
Transition at 1942-12-31T16:00:00Z from 25200 to 28800
Transition at 1945-03-14T15:00:00Z from 28800 to 32400
Transition at 1945-09-01T15:00:00Z from 32400 to 25200
Transition at 1947-03-31T17:00:00Z from 25200 to 28800
Transition at 1955-06-30T16:00:00Z from 28800 to 25200
Transition at 1959-12-31T16:00:00Z from 25200 to 28800
Transition at 1975-06-12T16:00:00Z from 28800 to 25200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I worked out is, start with passing `distantPast` to `nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition`:

```
someTimeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after: .distantPast)
```

This gets you the first transition date. Then do:

```
// second transition date
someTimeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after:
    someTimeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after: .distantPast)
)

// third transition date
someTimeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after:
    someTimeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after:
        someTimeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after: .distantPast)
    )
)
```

and so on. Of course, we will put this in a loop. The offset before and after the transition can be found by [`secondsFromGMT(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2292859-secondsfromgmt). We will pass a two dates that only differ by something like 1 second.

Also note that although this is named `nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition`, it also gives you non-DST transitions, which is exactly what you want, so that's great!

```
import Foundation

struct OffsetTransition {
    let instant: Date
    let offsetBefore: Int
    let offsetAfter: Int
}

var date = Date.distantPast
let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Some Time Zone ID")!
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime]

var transitions = [OffsetTransition]()

while date < Date() {
    guard let instant = timeZone.nextDaylightSavingTimeTransition(after: date) else {
        break
    }
    let offsetBefore = timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: instant.addingTimeInterval(-1))
    let offsetAfter = timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: instant)
    if offsetBefore == offsetAfter { continue }
    
    transitions.append(.init(instant: instant, offsetBefore: offsetBefore, offsetAfter: offsetAfter))
    
    print("Transition at \(dateFormatter.string(from: instant)) from \(offsetBefore) to \(offsetAfter)")
    date = instant
}
```

Note the `if offsetBefore == offsetAfter { continue }` check. I added this check because without it, it will sometimes produce transitions with `offsetBefore == offsetAfter`. This could be an indication that I am doing something wrong, but this check seems to fix the problem...

The output of this almost matches the output of a similar code using Java's `getTransitions`. However, there is one other slight problem that I found with this solution. For some timezones, such as `Europe/London`, the transition from the [local mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) to the standardised offset is missing, but for other timezones (e.g. `Asia/Hong_Kong`), it exists. For example, a similar code using `getTransitions` in Java would produce a "Transition at 1847-12-01T00:01:15Z from -75 to 0" for `Europe/London`, but the Swift code's output does not include this line. This is not too big of a problem for me though.